# How to use multiple base images with Docker?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to run my unit tests against the latest versions of PHP *and* Node, which means I need both installed into one image for it to work with [Bitbucket Pipelines](https://bitbucket.org/product/features/pipelines).

What I've been doing until now is to pick one or the other as my base, and then manually install the other. e.g., I've started with `php:5.6-fpm` as my base, and then installed Node:

```
# Dockerfile
FROM php:5.6-fpm

RUN docker-php-ext-install bcmath
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y git mercurial unzip nodejs
RUN npm set progress=false
RUN php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
RUN php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === 'e115a8dc7871f15d853148a7fbac7da27d6c0030b848d9b3dc09e2a0388afed865e6a3d6b3c0fad45c48e2b5fc1196ae') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
RUN php composer-setup.php --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
```

Is there any way to utilize *both* [PHP](https://hub.docker.com/_/php/) and [Node](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/) for my image, and then install some stuff on top of that (e.g. Composer and Yarn)?

Comment: Container should be simple, and do (usually) one thing. If you want to use both php and node, just define two containers and share a volume.

Comment: @MateuszSip Still learning Docker, but it appears Bitbucket Pipelines doesn't support this yet: https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/12757/ability-to-run-multiple-docker-containers So I don't have a choice but to build a single image unless I switch CI tools.

Comment: Looks like this feature is not available from Docker yet. See the discussions [here](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/12749) and [here](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/3378)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a image and `commit` it either only locally on your machine by:
`docker commit <container-id> image-name:tagname`
from: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/

then later use this image in new Dockerfile using `FROM image-name:tagname`

Everything that you will add to new Dockerfile will be stacked on top of that image you created with PHP and Node.js

Sometimes you could create several layers of images that will progress with different processes and functions. Very good reference is: https://hub.docker.com/u/million12/

So you can create a base image with PHP and then another using PHP image that has Node.js installed on it and then another with composer.

If you wish to export your images from your local machine you should register on docker hub and export to it or alternative service like quay.io

Hope that answered your question.

Comment: So....I still have to install either Node or PHP manually? I can't use to prebuilt images?

Comment: if you will find an image that suites your needs, then use it. Take a look at github repo to see how image is created. But at some point if you will need a custom image you will have to build your own, or use some public one as first base image but all next will have to come from your own custom additions.